# Data in Optical Fiber Communication?

Tags: optics, fiber-optics

Data is transferred in the form of light signals in an optical fiber. More will be the light signals/beams in a single strand at a time means more will be the data in that strand or a single strand of opitcal fiber can communicate 1 bit of data at a time ? What type of light in an optical fiber will correspond to 1 bit and what will correspond to more bits, mega bits, giga bits............ ? etc

Comment: have you researched this? there's a lot that's been written about it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> optical fiber can communicate 1 bit of data at a time ?

Let's consider the simplest kind of encoding in fiber optics, *on-off keying* (OOK). This means you send some light down the fiber to represent a 1, and you turn off the light to represent a 0.

Now, light propagates down the fiber at about $2\times 10^8$ m/s, because the index of refraction of glass is about 1.5.

So if you are turning your source on and off at 1 Gbps, and the fiber is longer than 0.2 m, there will be more than one bit "in flight" on the fiber at any given instant.

If you use a more complex modulation scheme, like *pulse-amplitude modulation* (PAM) or *quadrature amplitude modulation* (QAM), you can actually transmit more than 1 bit per symbol, and have more than one bit in each 0.2 m segment of fiber.

And, yes, it's also possible to have multiple fibers in a cable, and to send independent signals on different carrier wavelengths (called *wavelength division multiplexing*, WDM) on each fiber.

> What type of light in an optical fiber will correspond to 1 bit and what will correspond to more bits, mega bits, giga bits

On a single fiber, with a single wavelength, it's currently possible to send up to about 25 Gbps using OOK. Using more complex modulation, it's possible to send up to about 100 Gbps (maybe 400). Using WDM, it's possible to send up to about 1 terabit per second (Tbps), or maybe more, over a single fiber.

Comment: thanks alot @photon. "So if you are turning your source on and off at 1 Gbps,"  Does that mean that turning the source on and off at 10^9 times per second and if the length of the is 0.2 m then it means that at every second one bit is being transmitted ?

Comment: No, it means every second 1 billion bits are transmitted. If the fiber is 1 m long, 5 bits are traveling through the fiber at any moment. If the fiber is 100 m long, there are 500 different bits travelling though the fiber at any moment.

Comment: ok so at what rate i will have to turn my source on and of to transmit 1 bit per 1 second and what should be the length of fiber in that case ? may be i am teasing you but thats the last question.

Comment: You can transmit one bit per second by turning the source on or off each second depending which value you want to send. The maximum fiber length depends on a lot of details about the source and receiver you use, type of fiber, etc. But this becomes an engineering question rather than physics.

Comment: @Alex You should turn the source on or off once per second, if you are using on-off keying (the simplest modulation). The length of the fiber should be long enough to go from the thing that is sending the data to the thing that is receiving the data. It's a lightbulb, not a magic spell.